# Getting a remainder of the numbers not divisible

Tags: javascript

I am converting a string into a number and then converting that number into minutes. So I'm checking if the number is divisible by 60 and then multiplying that number by 60. That part works fine. But, I'm left with a remainder of the numbers that are not divisible by 60.

for example, 2 hours and 23 minutes my formula at the moment will only return 120. I need to find the solution to add the remaining 23 minutes.

```
let item = "2h 22min"

let timed = parseInt(item) % 60;
let atimed = timed * 60;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working taking only hour because when you parseInt it takes only first number so it's just taking 2. so to fix this you need to split by space and then you will get hour and minute.

```
const item = "2h 30m"
const time = parseInt(item) // this returns only 2.
```

```js
const item = "2h 30m"
const [h, m] = item.split(" ");
const hour = parseInt(h);
const min = parseInt(m);
const atimed = (hour * 60) + min;

console.log(atimed);
```

Comment: This works, but I never seen a variable named in an array? like [h, m], can you explain this part?

Comment: it's es6 feature. destructuring array assignment. [ h, m ] means h is first element in array and m is second element in array. you can even give default values to these variables. [ h = 0, m = 0] = item.split(" ").

Answer (score 1):

The code which you are doing is wrong.

`parseInt('2h 22mins')` will be just 2.

Try like the following, you need to split that string then calculate hours and minutes.

```js
function convert(item){
  var atimed = "";
  var full = item.split(' ');
  if(full.length == 2){
    let hour = parseInt(full[0]);
    let mins = parseInt(full[1]);
    atimed = (hour * 60)+mins;
  } else if(full.length == 1){
    let mins = parseInt(full[0]);
    atimed = mins
  }
  return atimed
}

console.log(convert("2h 22min"));
console.log(convert("30min"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like below.

```
var item = "2h 22min"
var time = item.split(" ");
var hours = parseInt(time[0]) * 60;
var minutes = parseInt(time[1]);

var totalMinutes = hours + minutes;
```